# Play 2.4 tests with Slick, specs2 and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, scala, specs2, playframework-2.4, slick-3.0

What I want is to run my tests with the same databse engine, same evolutions and config as in production. My db is PostgreSQL 9.4 and I use Slick 3.0.0 to access it.

And here the problems:

- In case of parallel tests execution I have several evolutions run at once on the same db. That leads to errors.
- In case of sequential tests execution I have another error with thread pool.

Here the details.

I use evolutions to init the db for each test. For that purpose I prepared a base spec class:

```
 class DatabaseSpecification extends PlaySpecification {
  protected val defaultAppBuilder =
    new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .configure(ConfigurationLoader.loadFirst("application.test.override.conf", "application.test.conf"))

  protected def afterEach(app: Application) = {
    recreateDbSchema(app)
  }

  private def recreateDbSchema(app: Application) = {
    val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](app)
    import dbConfig.driver.api._

    val recreateSchema: DBIO[Unit] = DBIO.seq(
      sqlu"drop schema public cascade",
      sqlu"create schema public"
    )    
    Await.ready(dbConfig.db.run(recreateSchema), 5 seconds)
  }

  abstract class DatabaseContext() extends WithApplication(defaultAppBuilder.build()) {
    protected val injector = implicitApp.injector

    override def around[T](t: => T)(implicit evidence$2: AsResult[T]): Result = super.around {
      try {
        t
      } finally {
        afterEach(implicitApp)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

where `application.test.override.conf` is config file for the tests.

Also there are couple tests in an ancestor spec:

```
"save1 and query" in new DatabaseContext {
  // create new user
  val accountRepo = injector.instanceOf[SystemUserRepo]
  val user = new SystemUser(id = 0, login = "admin", passwordHash = "", role = Role.Administrator)
  val futureUserId = accountRepo.create(user)

  // check if user id is greater then zero
  val userId = await(futureUserId)(5 second)
  userId must be_>(0)
}

"second one1" in new DatabaseContext {
  1 mustEqual 1
}
```

If I run the whole spec's tests in parallel (default) then get exception `Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state![An evolution has not been applied properly. Please check the problem and resolve it manually before marking it as resolved.]
@6mk338l87: Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state!` in one of the tests.

If I run it sequential `class AccountRepositoryTest extends DatabaseSpecification { sequential ... }` another exeception appears

```
Task slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2@2744dcae rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@16d0e521[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 3]
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2@2744dcae rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@16d0e521[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.runSynchronousDatabaseAction(DatabaseComponent.scala:224)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.runSynchronousDatabaseAction(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.runInContext(DatabaseComponent.scala:201)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.runInContext(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.runInternal(DatabaseComponent.scala:75)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.runInternal(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.run(DatabaseComponent.scala:72)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.run(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
    at repository.GenericCRUD$class.create(GenericCRUD.scala:50)
    at repository.GenericCRUDImpl.create(GenericCRUD.scala:70)
    at unit.repositories.AccountRepositoryTest$$anonfun$3$$anon$1.delayedEndpoint$unit$repositories$AccountRepositoryTest$$anonfun$3$$anon$1$1(AccountRepositoryTest.scala:39)
    at unit.repositories.AccountRepositoryTest$$anonfun$3$$anon$1$delayedInit$body.apply(AccountRepositoryTest.scala:35)
```

It happens on line `val futureUserId = accountRepo.create(user)`. Sadly but I have no idea why the second exception throws. Btw, I prefer to run tests in parallel of course but don't know how to achive it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To simulate any JDBC env during tests, you can have a look at the [Acolyte approach](http://acolyte.eu.org/), which allows isolated unit tests for the persistence layer.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't help me because I have sql-functions in my db.

Comment: As soon as the unit testing of the persistence layer doesn't aim to test the DB engine and/or functions but the application code that works with this DB, the requirement is to be able to define within these tests some JDBC connections accepting the same statement&returning the same JDBC results(resultset|update count|error) as when it plays with the DB.Acolyte does it,whatever is the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you should running Database tests with `sequential` else it will fail.
The Thread Pool error comes from:

```
protected val defaultAppBuilder =
    new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .configure(ConfigurationLoader.loadFirst("application.test.override.conf", "application.test.conf"))
```

it should be a function:

```
protected def defaultAppBuilder =
    new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .configure(ConfigurationLoader.loadFirst("application.test.override.conf", "application.test.conf"))
```

then it will start working. We do this aswell, however we have abstract class which has a `val application` where we could configure stuff and a `def app` which will just do a `def app = application.build()` so that we still could extend the GuiceApplictionBuilder.

Currently I had the same error first, you definitly don't want to have the same application reused for each tests.

So try that and you have a really good functional test suite for play applications.

However the only thing we don't do is the `public drop schema` we rely on evolutions to fix that by cleaning them up. If they are wrong we instantly see the errors.

Comment: Hi Christian! I've changed val to def but unfourtantly have the same error with the thread pool as before. Tell me please how you run evolution downs after a test?

Comment: My Evolutions running this way: 
 ```override def after = {
    val dbapi = app.injector.instanceOf[DBApi]
    Evolutions.cleanupEvolutions(dbapi.database(prefix))
  } ``` 
and then have a
```with AfterEach``` on your test classes. However that works with your DatabaseContext, too.

Comment: Christian if you don't mind show me your base spec class please.